# UUID as default for MySQL id column

Tags: mysql, uuid

I am trying to add a column to an existing table in MySql 8.0.17. The column needs to contain a UUID and I am trying to set it as a default value.

This is the statement I am executing

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN UUID varchar(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT (UUID());
```

However I am getting the following error

> Error Code: 1674. Statement is unsafe because it uses a system function that may return a different value on the slave.

I have read from other posts that it is possible to create a Trigger on the table however i would like to find out whether it is possible to set it directly as the default value on the column.

Also, what would be the advantage of using a binary conversion of the UUID over just a simple UUID ?

Eg.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN UUID binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), true));
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

assigning `UUID()` as DEFAULT value won't work, because It does not guarantee that the same value will be generated on your replica. That is why using TRIGGER is good option for new records (insertions).

If your intention is to update current records as well, you can write an update statement

```
update myTable
set UUID = UUID()
```

---

your column is of type   `binary(16)` which means UUID data is implicitly converted to binary. using `UUID_TO_BIN` is not needed.

EDIT:

CHAR/VARCHAR is the human-readable format. whereas, binary is the compact format.
That means compressing the 32 characters (36 or more with separators) to the 16-bit format or back to the human-readable format.

If you dont mind about reading UUID, best is to use binary format

Comment: Hi Dervis, thanks for your response. So do you suggest i set the column as varchar(36) or binary(16) ? And what is the advantage of one over the other one? Thanks.

Comment: You can set your column as `CHAR(36)` as it would always same length.

Comment: CHAR/VARCHAR is the human-readable format. whereas, binary is the compact format. If you dont mind about reading UUID, best is to use binary format

Answer (score 1):

Change VARCHAR to CHAR, this will let you use 16bit.

Old Method

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN UUID varchar(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT (UUID());
```

New Method

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN UUID BINARY(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()));
```

Comment: Why `BINARY(36)` for the "new method"? IAFAIK a `BINARY(16)` should be enough for an UUID. Besides the different size this is exactly what is included in the question so I don't see how this will answer the question. Also `16bit` can not be correct, may be you mean `16 bytes`?

Comment: I'm getting the error with both methods